# Sum of COUNTIFS with multiple OR criteria and AND

Tags: excel

I figure there must be a similar issue on here somewhere but I could not find it...

Issue is related the discussion here: http://excelxor.com/2014/09/28/countifs-multiple-or-criteria-for-one-or-two-criteria_ranges/

Data:

Column A contains items such as: "0 - Include" and "1 - Exclude" up to "7 - Exclude". Column B contains the same items.

I want to count the number of events of Exclude in column A that coincides with an Exclude in column B regardless of the prefix on the exclude (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, or 7).

I tried the following formula where the 1 - Exclude, etc are located on another sheet. And the I3-I9 correspond to cells that contain the values for 1 - Exclude to 7 - Exclude. But the formula constantly returns an error.

```
    =SUM(COUNTIFS(Merged_Full_Text!F2:F400,{I3;I4;I5;I6;I7;I8;I9},Merged_Full_Text!G2:G400,{I3,I4,I5,I6,I7,I8,I9}))

    0 - Include 0 - Include.
    2 - Exclude 5 - Exclude.
    3 - Exclude 3 - Exclude.
    5 - Exclude 1 - Exclude.
    0 - Include 1 - Exclude.
    2 - Exclude 0 - Include.
```

So, the count that comes from this should = 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like,

```
=COUNTIFS(Merged_Full_Text!F$2:F$400, "*exclude", Merged_Full_Text!G$2:G$400, "*exclude")
```

I've assumed that your data does not irregularly terminate in a comma or period.